# Python google api search dateRestrict/sort not returning results

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get date restriction/filtering to recieve only websites published within a specified date range, in my example I am trying to search for Suez canal news, before the blockage occurred, if I use google I can achieve this manually with a customised date range, so I should expect similar results as shown below
[image: Google customised date range]

When I run the following code it returns no results:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = "my API key"
cx = "my CSE ID"

service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)

# Define search query and date range
query = "Suez canal news"
start_date = "20210315"
end_date = "20210317"

# Build the search request with date filtering
request = service.cse().list(
    q=query, cx=cx, num = 10, 
    sort="date:r:" + start_date + ":" + end_date
)

# Execute the request and print the results
response = request.execute()

for item in response.get("items", []):
    print(item["title"])
    print(item["link"])
    print("\n")
```

I have tried using date formats of YYYY-MM-DD and YYYYMMDD alongside with attempting `dateRestrict="<<"+start_date+"TO"+end_date` and `dateRestrict="d"+start_date+".."+end_date` when using dateRestrict I get some results but these are just the latest results from google not filtered to the specified range.

I can get the expected results using before: and after: e.g. "suez canal news after:2021-03-15 before:2021-03-17", but I would like to understand the correct way of using dateRestrict and sort to achieve this result.